# Problems with SQL sum aggregate function

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to run a query on a database that has 3 tables: COURSE, SECTION, ENROLL.

They are creating as such:

```
create table COURSE
(
    Cno     varchar(9) primary key, 
    Cname   varchar(50),
    Credit  int check (Credit > 0)
);

create table SECTION
(
    Cno     varchar(9) REFERENCES COURSE(cno),
    Sno     varchar(9),
    Semester    varchar(15) check(Semester in('Fall','Spring','Summer')), 
    Year    int, 
    Sid     varchar(9) primary key 
);

create table ENROLL
(
    Mno     varchar(9) REFERENCES STUDENT(Mno),
    Sid     varchar(9) REFERENCES SECTION(Sid),
    Grade   CHAR check(Grade in('A','B','C','D','F')),
    primary key(Mno,Sid)
);
```

I'm trying to run a `SUM` on all the credits for classes that a student is enrolled in. This is how I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
select 
    SUM(select Credit 
        from COURSE c 
        where c.Cno = (select s.Cno 
                       from SECTION s 
                       where s.Sid = (select Sid 
                                      from ENROLL 
                                      where Mno = @mNum));
```

However I'm getting an error in Visual Studio that says

> Incorrect syntax near 'select'   (the second select statement)

What is it that is wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an IN rather than an = if for example a Mno can enroll in multiple sections

```
select sum(Credit) 
   from COURSE c 
  where c.Cno in (select s.Cno 
                    from SECTION s 
                   where s.Sid in (select Sid 
                                    from ENROLL where Mno = @mNum)
                  )
```

Comment: Ah, you are very correct! That portion was overlooked and I have not tested my query yet! Thank you!!

Comment: if you are taking in you need to take group by c.Cno  because there can be multiple c.Cno's

Comment: since all are primary keys c.Cno , s.Sid and Mno this query with in as well as = will work

Comment: @nikhil Have a look at the table structure of ENROLL table. It's the combination of (Mno,Did) which is a primary key. So that means single Mno can have multiple Sid and so the = will fail if there multiple sections a Mno is enrolled in

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph i also thought that at the first place thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

see if it works:

```
select sum(Credit) from COURSE c where c.Cno in 
(select s.Cno from SECTION s where s.Sid in (select Sid from ENROLL where Mno = @mNum)) 
group by c.Cno;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is the group by necessary though?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select SUM((select Credit from COURSE c where c.Cno = 
(select s.Cno from SECTION s where s.Sid = (select Sid from ENROLL where Mno = @mNum)));
```

Comment: Hi! The issue was not the parentheses, rather the way I was trying to use the aggregate function. My issue has been solved already! Thanks for answering though!

Comment: @Ekha it would be a good idea to test out the query using online db-fiddle or any of the online database test websites